# Full page width slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am currently creating a website which at the top of the page I am trying to create a slider which when you use next and previous buttons, the content below changes to match that item.

For example, [Honda Bikes](http://www.honda.co.uk/motorcycles/sporttourer/#!/vfr800/) has this which is shown in the image below. I am after something exactly like this with content changing below the slider to match the item. I have had a look at the page, and it seems like they are using some kind of jQuery carousel.

If someone has a link to a, I presume, jQuery plugin that would be a great help to get me started.

[image: Full page slider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like Honda created their own jQuery carousel plugin.

There are plenty of [great slideshow plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/jquery-carousel-plugins/) available, here's a [cool jQuery slideshow](http://ryanflorence.com/jquery-slideshow/) included on the Honda site.

Answer (score 0):

*[Top 10 jQuery Carousel Plugins For 2013](http://www.webhostingjams.com/top-10-jquery-carousel-plugins-for-2013/)* has a couple of good ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this plugin: [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php). It's easy to use, flexible and has many features.